# PHP - Having an issue with my login system

Tags: php

Bear with me while i explain this. So I have my login.php which redirects the user to a new page when you log in and is processed by login_functions.inc.php. I have my index.php which is my homepage before you log in. I have my loggedin.inc.php which displays navigation and header information for when you are logged in and allows you to browse around pages you wouldn't be able to if you were logged out. And i have my loggedout.inc.php which displays the login form for pages accessible when you are not logged in.

The problem is, When you log in I want loggedin.inc.php to display for all of the pages on my website including those that also display the loggedout.inc.php file when you are logged out. loggedin.inc.php and loggedout.inc.php are essentially two different header.inc.php files. They display depending if you are logged in or logged out of the website.

Now i've had this working before, but somewhere along the way it broke and i can't figure out how to fix it. Here are the snippets of code that create this process. The only page i have setup for when you are logged out is the home page. Which should be viewable both with the loggedin.inc.php header file and the loggedout.inc.php header file depending if you are logged in and logged out. I'm using sessions to keep track of your user_id from the database for your username info.

**index.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

$page_title = 'You can now browse around the entire website!';
include ('loggedin.inc.php');

} else {

$page_title = 'Please log in to view the rest of the website!';
include ('loggedout.inc.php');

}
?>
```

this code worked before but apparently it's not working now. When you log in, your user_id becomes set in a session varriable from the database and carries with you through every page on the website. Every other process of my login system works except for this one.

When I log in and browse around my site it keeps using the loggedin.inc.php file for all the pages except when i navigate to the index.php it displays the loggedout.inc.php file and i can even manually type in a url for a logged in page and the loggedin.inc.php file will display again. This isn't a question of whether or not the session variable is set, because it definitely stays set.

Comment: I suppose you have `session_start();` hidden somewhere? (*They always leave that mention out*)

Comment: sorry i was trying to get my code to display lol, still new to stackoverflow.. And yes, since either loggedin.inc.php or loggedout.inc.php display on every single page the session_start(); lines are used at the very top of both of those files.

Comment: What's with the code `S-T-I-T-C-H`? Your original question was fine.

Comment: @Egahtrac ya gotta have it on each page you plan on using $_SESSION. Haven't read the entire post but that's a start.

Comment: I know what's wrong but i still don't have a solution. session_start(); is not present at the top of the index.php file so therefore the $_SESSION[user_id] is not set when you view this page, it only becomes set after the if statement is used. But when in put the session_start(); at the top of the index page, it is starting a second time when the header files are called and it displays an error that breaks my page layout.

Comment: Not just both files, but ALL files. You'd need to show us the code for all your pages that uses `$_SESSION`. @Egahtrac

Comment: I need an if statement for the header files that will start the session if it is not already started.

Comment: Either way, you still have to include `session_start();` even if a session exists or not (or set), because you're including the word `$_SESSION` in `if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))` @Egahtrac

Comment: I just fixed it.. I just wrote it as @session_start(); so that silly message doesn't display at all. Thanks for helping me troubleshoot this everyone!

Comment: [You probably want to read this.](http://us2.php.net/session_start)

Comment: So, problem solved then? @Egahtrac because of the missing `session_start();` in your `index.php` file?

Comment: Yeah, so simple but it sincerely escaped me i couldn't figure it out. That's what happens when you sit there coding for 9 hours straight

Comment: If you want to close the question, I can put in an answer from my said comments. @Egahtrac or you can leave it open, it's up to you. However, it will remain in the unanswered category otherwise.

Comment: Yeah let's go ahead and close it!

Comment: I posted it below. @Egahtrac cheers, glad it all worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to include `session_start();` whether a session exists or not (or is set or not), because you're including the word `$_SESSION` in `if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))`

Therefore your code would resemble:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

$page_title = 'You can now browse around the entire website!';
include ('loggedin.inc.php');

} else {

$page_title = 'Please log in to view the rest of the website!';
include ('loggedout.inc.php');

}
?>
```